# I would like to parse an html source string to find a specific tag in Java

Tags: java, html-parsing, jsoup

So I have the following html source:

```
<form action='http://example.com' method='get'>

        <P>Some example text here.</P>
        <input type='text' class='is-input' id='agent_name' name='deviceName' placeholder='Device Name'>
        <input type='hidden' name='p' value='firefox'>
        <input type='hidden' name='email' value='example@example.com'>
        <input type='hidden' name='k' value='cITBk236gyd56oiY0fhk6lpuo9nt61Va'>
        <p><input type='submit' class='btn-blue' style='margin-top:15px;' value='Install'></p>
</form>
```

Unfortunately this html source is saved as a string.
I would like to parse it using something like jsoup. and obtain the following String:
`<input type='hidden' name='k' value='cITBk236gyd56oiY0fhk6lpuo9nt61Va'>`

or better yet, only grab the following value: `cITBk236gyd56oiY0fhk6lpuo9nt61Va`

The problem I'm running into is that:

a) that value: `cITBk236gyd56oiY0fhk6lpuo9nt61Va` is consistently changing I cannot look for the entire html tag.

So, I am looking for a better way to do this.
Here is what I currently have that does not seem to be working:

```
//tried use thing, but java was angry for some reason
Jsoup.parse(myString);

// so I used this instead. 
org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.parse(myString);

// in this case I just tried to select the entire tag. Elements
elements = doc.select("<input name=\"k\"
value=\"cITBkdxJTFd56oiY0fhk6lUu8Owt61Va\" type=\"hidden\">");

//yeah this does not seem to work. I assume it's not a string anymorebut a document. Not sure if it 
//would attempt to print anyway.
System.out.println(elements);
```

so I guess I can't use select, but even if this would work. I was not sure how to place select that part of the tag and place it into a new string.

Comment: If you can add a unique id to the input element that would be great for parsing. If you can't, you can also try using the `name` attribute to find the element and return its `value` attribute.

Comment: Did you check out this page? http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/selector-syntax

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis thanks for your help. I didn't realize Jsoup could do that. After you said that, I googled for the proper syntax. And was able to parse and complete what I needed. I noticed what I did, was an exact answer as another answer response. Thanks again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try this way

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(myString);
Elements elements = doc.select("input[name=k]");
System.out.println(elements.attr("value"));
```

output:

```
cITBk236gyd56oiY0fhk6lpuo9nt61Va
```

Comment: Wow, I literally just typed that out. and you provided me hte proper answer. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this call to `select` to get the elements:

```
elements = doc.select("input[name=k][value=cITBkdxJTFd56oiY0fhk6lUu8Owt61Va]")
```

In this context, `elements` must be an [`Elements`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Elements.html) object. If you need to extract data from `elements`, you can use one of these (among others, obviously):

```
elements.html(); // HTML of all elements
elements.text(); // Text contents of all elements
elements.get(i).html(); // HTML of the i-th element
elements.get(i).text(); // Text contents of the i-th element
elements.get(i).attr("value"); // The contents of the "value" attribute of the i-th element
```

To iterate over `elements`, you can use any of these:

```
for(Element element : elements)
    element.html(); // Or whatever you want

for(int i=0;i<elements.size();i++)
    elements.get(i).html(); // Or whatever you want
```

[Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) is an *excellent* library. The `select` method uses (lightly) modified [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html) for document queries. You can check the valid syntax for the method in [the Jsoup javadocs](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/select/Selector.html).